# How to use openzeppelin contracts for a specific version

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

Consider me a beginner to writing smart contracts.
My question is, openzeppelin's contracts are using latest versions of solidity (by their repo). How do I use say 0.6 version, do they have it available?

This is because I'm also importing another contract which is of 0.6, so I can't use it with OpenZeppelin's contracts which are 0.8

Comment: You need to download a lower version of openZeppelin contracts library, npm openZeppelin v4 library use 0.8 and v3.4.0 use 0.7 , I don’t recommend you to use a lower version than v3. The best way is to try to update that contract to 0.7 and there is no huge breaking change between 6 and 7 look in the documentation https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.1/070-breaking-changes.html

Comment: I'm trying to use chainlinks VRF for random number, its ^0.6.6 so it cant be changed, so which version should i download? lower than v3 i assume?

Comment: npm i @openzeppelin/contracts@3.4.0 try this version, the compiler version is between 6 and 8

Comment: sorry i thought all v3 has the 0.7.0 but that was wrong -> this version has solidity 0.6 npm i @openzeppelin/contracts@3.2.0 but try the above comment first

Comment: all good, it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using npm and if I have to download version 3.9.0 then I would at first delete the existing openzeppelin file(if exist) then write `npm install "@openzeppelin@^3.9.0"` , it should work.

Comment: As said by Majd the correct command should be `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts@3.2.0`